# How to connect QR scanner module to Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: pi-zero-w

How can i connect QR scanner module to PI Zero W

QR Scanner additional info: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32895991920.html

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what options do you see when you examine the connector pinout?

Comment: what do you mean with options?

Comment: The options are the interfaces provided by the device.  You have to find an interface which both the device and the Raspberry Pi have.  You then need to be good with s soldering iron as the connectors on that device are tiny.  Why not buy a simpler to interface device?

Comment: @joan thank you for the explanation. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

That cable can be a hassle to work with, maybe try to find a breakout board that would work with it.
But anyway, you need to connect the devices GND, RX and TX pins to the Pis serial TX/RX pins. Your device seems to be powered by 3.3V so they should be level compatible. And looks like you also need to connect the nTrig pin to a any suitable GPIO pin to be able to trigger a reading.